# cannot perform override in class inheritance in ADO .NET Entity Model edmx

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inheritance

I have to build a .net web application accessing tables of an existing db.

The db uses different tables for different companies: customers in company "ACorp" are stored in table "ACorpCustomers", those in company "B" are stored in table "BCorpCustomers".

Using ADO .NET Entity Model, I created a different Db Context for each Company:

```
public partial class ACorpContext : DbContext
    {
        public ACorpContext()
            : base("name=ACorpContext")
        {
        }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<ACorpCustomer> ACorpCustomers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The edmx generates also the class

```
public partial class ACorpCustomer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I created a parent class Customer to be used in the application, with the same properties:

```
public class ACorpCustomer
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I havent't found a way to let the specific entity ACorpCustomers inherit from the parent Customer; the edmx returns the inheritance error, but there is no way to override the properties.

**Update**

In order to avoid edmx file usage, this is what I finally tried out:

1. I disabled the __MigrationHistory sql table creation using the AutomaticMigrationsEnabled parameter:

   ```
        internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDomain.Models.ACorpContext>
        {
            public Configuration()
            {
                AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            }
        }
   ```
2. I disabled the db initialization in the App.config file setting
   disableDatabaseInitialization="true"
3. Then I added a an ADO .NET Entity Model but chose the "code first from database".
   In order to be sure not to change the db from the model, I disabled the DB Initializer:

   ```
        public ACorpContext()
            : base("name=ACorpContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<ACorpContext>(null);
        }
   ```

Now I expect to be my responsability to be keep in sync the domain model with the db.
Anyway, I feel sure that in case of misalignment no attempt will be done to modify the db.
Without the edmx, I have no more limitations defining inheritance from an abstract class Customer.

I cannot understand why Visual Studio considers this as "Code First" approach, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition

```
public partial class ACorpCustomer
```

has nothing to do with inheritance. `partial` is a .NET moderator that signifies that your class definition is a part of the bigger definition. For example if you have your class split between 2 code files. .Net "puts" them together and you endup with one `type`

Here what you seem need to do is

```cs
public abstract class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class ACorpCustomer : Customer
{
    // may be, some unique properties here
}

public class BCorpCustomer : Customer
{
    // may be, some unique properties here
}
```

The properties `Name` and `Phone` don't even need to be `virtual`. Looking back into your title, there is nothing that you need to `override`. Nothing that I see..

Comment: The admx forces to create the class ACorpCustomer with its properties, and it's raccomended not to be manually modifed because it would be overwritten every time the admx is syncronized with the db structure. Because the class is defined as partial by the edmx, I can integrate it with inheritance, but  I cannot remove or override any property.

Comment: @AndreaRossi to have a full disclosure, I never worked with Code-First approach. Only DB-first. We manually set all out models and used different techniques, like split-tables, inheritance, etc. so, I can't have a good code-first judgement at this point

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial in Code-First, which you can (and should) use with an [existing database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database#:%7E:text=%20Code%20First%20to%20an%20Existing%20Database%20,a%20model%20it%E2%80%99s%20time%20to%20use...%20More%20).  Just map the single Customer entity to the correct table for each DbContext:

```
    public partial class ACorpContext : MyBaseDbContext
    {
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("ACorpContext");
        }
    
        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Using this solution I am forced to use the __MigrationHistory table; but in this project I cannot add any table to this database. What I need is a pure database first approach.

Comment: You don’t need migrations with this approach.